# Where I find the usb-creator.exe that was included in previous versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: live-usb

Back about 10.10 the Live CD contained a Windows executable named **usb-creator.exe**

(It was a Windows version of Startup Disk Creator).

Is an up to date version of this file still available?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the information about [usb-creator](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/usb-creator) on Launchpad. Latest version is [0.2.52](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/0.2.52).

If you want the Windows installer: [​liveusb-creator-3.12.0-setup.exe](https://fedorahosted.org/releases/l/i/liveusb-creator/liveusb-creator-3.12.0-setup.exe) (13M) (​[ChangeLog](https://github.com/lmacken/liveusb-creator/commits/master)) (SHA1: ed3c8355821d419e68f3e7cce0ceef4c5b42aafb).

Comment: Nope, the one you linked to is Fedora, I am interested in the Windows version of usb-creator. If you look in 10.10 desktop iso you will see the one I refer to. I don't think it works with the latest version of Ubuntu though.

Comment: That should be the same one (or per new release an improved one :D ). usb-creator.exe is **cross-platform** so it does not matter if its from the Fedora installation or from any other you can find it on.

Comment: Not to be ungrateful: The Fedora app requires installation to hard drive the Ubuntu one does not. The Fedora one seems very slow compared to the Ubuntu one. I could not get the Fedora app to produce a persistence file. I am looking for a Windows version of "Startup Disk Creator". Liveusb-creator is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Except for lack of persistence the final product is what I am looking for, normal splash screen, not dos like, like UNetbootin.

Comment: Fedora uses a different method of providing persistence than Ubuntu, persistence overlay vs casper-rw.